# I get error when i use mysqli select

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php if($_POST) {  
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','movie_posters');
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '"$username"'");

} ?>
```

When I try this code on WAMP, I get error like; this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcifR.jpg
What can I do ?

Comment: You are missing periods: `"SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'"`

Comment: Sidenote: `htmlspecialchars` doesn't protect against SQL injection, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` does, while passing DB connection to it, but works only after DB connection has been established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use single and double quotes in your query.
This is the right way:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Otherwise, you will not print $username's value.

Comment: Correction: that's the less-wrong way. SQL injection is still a major security concern. :-)

Comment: I just shared my thoughts on the problem described above, but you're right - it is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put periods before and after you variable.
In your example:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
```

Comment: ok already answered in the comments before.