# How can I get url of input file?

Tags: php

After pressing a button, I'd like to get the url from an input file.

```
<input name="poster" type="file">
$poster = $_POST['poster'];
```

Then I want to use the url like this;

```
<img src="<?php echo $poster; ?>" alt="" />
```

But its not working. What can I do?

Comment: You should start by accepting answers before posting new ones. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26875499/)

Comment: i just forget, sorry.

Comment: Your code is unfinished and missing a lot of parts. Namely form tags, a post method and a valid enctype. You're also working with the `$_FILES` superglobal http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and not `$_POST`. Consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php and http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: I checked that links but I don't get how can I get url from input file, can you explain that with an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File is not the same as other inputs like text or radio, it cannot be simply used by `$_POST['file_name']`, read some examples first please.
Here is one good example:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp.

About url, it is you to design where to put the file with `move_uploaded_file()`. If you don't move it, it will be in the temporary directory and cannot be used. Since you can move it anywhere you like, it is basically you to design the url you use latter to show the uploaded image.

Comment: please take a look at this, maybe it will help you. File is not the same as other inputs. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php